# "Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy " in a specific tenant returns errors

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I have an issue with `Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy cmdlet returning errors in a specific customer tenants. majority` of tenants the cmdlet is working fine. The csv returned is empty.

my code

```
$allpolicies = Get-AzureADMSConditionalAccessPolicy 

$allpolicies | ForEach-Object {
    New-object -typename PSobject -property @{
        ID                           = $_.Id
        DisplayName                  = $_.DisplayName
        Policy_State                 = $_.State
        Includedapps                 = ($_.Conditions).Applications.IncludeApplications -join ';'
        Users_Applied_The_Policy     = ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeUsers -join ';'
        Groups_Applied_The_Policy    = ($_.Conditions).Users.IncludeGroups -join ';'
        Locations_Applied_The_Policy = ($_.Conditions).Locations.includelocations -join ';'
    }
} | Sort-Object ID, DisplayName, Policy_State, Includedapps, Users_Applied_Policy, Groups_Applied_Policy, Locations_Applied | Export-Csv -Path C:\CAccessResults3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

See attached the error I'm getting.
[image]

Comment: if a tenant chooses Linux as a platform under any Conditional Access Policy, the commands to get policies throws a nasty error. : https://githubhot.com/repo/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-powershell/issues/31

Comment: Thank you @RahulKumarShaw-MT for this, i believe the issue is being caused by the linux preview feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in my environment getting the same error if any conditional access policy has created for Device Platform as Linux.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Solution : For Workaround Removed the polcies for Linux device plateform.It is working as expected.As from 1st picture Linux is still in preview state

[image]

[image]